# Get children's posts in parents with Doctrine Extensions Tree Nested set

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-query

I'm using the [nested set](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md) behaviour in Symfony2 with [StofDoctrineExtension](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle).

The category and post model are well configured, and the category tree works fine.

To show the posts of a category I use this query from my repository:

```
public function findAllPosts($category)
{
    return $this->queryAllPosts($category)->getResult();
}

public function queryAllPosts($category)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $query = $em->createQuery('
        SELECT p, c FROM AppBundle:Post p JOIN p.category c
        WHERE c.slug = :category
        ORDER BY p.created DESC
    ');

    $query->setParameter('category', $category);

    return $query;
}
```

But how could I do to show the posts of the children of the categories too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way. The query would be like this:

```
/*
 * GET POSTS FROM PARENT AND CHILDREN
 */
public function getPostsParentAndChildren($children)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $posts = $em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select(array('p', 'c'))
        ->from('AppBundle:Post', 'p')
        ->join('p.category', 'c')
        ->where('c.id IN (:children)')
        ->orderBy('p.created', 'DESC')
        ->getQuery();

    $posts->setParameter('children', $children);

    return $posts->getResult();
}
```

We pass an array with the children to the query, which we obtain with the function getChildren($categoryId). Remember that you have to pass the id (with this query), so you could get the ids like this:

```
    $category = $repo->findOneBy(array('slug' => $slug1));

    $children = $repo->getChildren($category);

    $childrenIds[] = $category->getId();
    foreach ($children as $child){
        $id = $child->getId();
        $childrenIds[] = $id;
    }

    $posts = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')->getPostsParentAndChildren($childrenIds);
```

Answer (score 2):

If your `CategoryRepository` inherits from `NestedTreeRepository` you could do something like this:

```
$categories = $em->getRepository('XBundle:Category')
  ->childrenQueryBuilder($category)
  ->addSelect('posts')
  ->join('node.posts', 'posts')
  ->getQuery()
  ->getResult();

foreach ($categories as $category) {
  $category->getPosts();
  // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this in one query which will be close to this one as i am not pro SQL it usually takes me time and tests before i get it right but this is where i would start :

```
 SELECT parent.* , children.* FROM 
          (SELECT p, c FROM AppBundle:Post p JOIN p.category c WHERE c.slug = :category) AS parent 
          INNER JOIN 
          (SELECT p1 FROM  AppBundle:Post p1 JOIN p.category c1 ON c1.parent = parent.id ) AS children
```

not sure if you need to do the ON inside the inner select or the wrapper select for the join but you can try :)

Comment: It gives a semantical error with '('. I'll keep trying different solutions with SQL, at least now I can focus there. Thanks!

Comment: I knew it would give some kind of error haha but this is the way with sub query better than using a loop.